# Java, Spring : Text comparison sometimes adding null entries.

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, postgresql, spring-mvc

I am working on a Spring-MVC application using Hibernate as ORM and Postgres DB in which I have note taking application. Whenever an user edits a note, I am comparing the old entry in DB and the new text given by user. I am separating the text by dot operator and comparing them. The differences I am putting in 2 columns, namely oldText and newText.

The problem is sometimes I am getting 'null' entry prepended to the text. I have tried some ways to mitigate this issue, alas no success. Can someone help me with this. Thanks a lot.

Code :

```
List<String> oldTextList = Arrays.asList(mnotes1.getMnotetext().split("(\\.|\\n)"));
List<String> newTextList = Arrays.asList(mnotes.getMnotetext().split("(\\.|\\n)"));
int counter = Math.max(oldTextList.size(), newTextList.size());
String oldString = null;
String newString = null;

for (int current = 0; current < counter; current++) {

    if (oldTextList.size() <= current) {
        oldString = " ";
        newString = newTextList.get(current);

    } else if (newTextList.size() <= current) {
        oldString = oldTextList.get(current);
        newString = " ";
    } else {
        if (isLineDifferent(oldTextList.get(current), newTextList.get(current))) {
            noEdit = true;
            oldString += oldTextList.get(current);
            newString += newTextList.get(current);
        }
    }

    if(oldString != null && newString != null) {
        if(!(groupNoteHistory.getNewNoteText() == null)){
            if(!(groupNoteHistory.getNewNoteText().isEmpty())) {
                groupNoteHistory.setNewNoteText(groupNoteHistory.getNewNoteText() + "."+newString);
            }else {
                groupNoteHistory.setNewNoteText(newString);
            }
        }else {
            groupNoteHistory.setNewNoteText(newString);
        }
        if(!(groupNoteHistory.getOldText() == null)) {
            if(!(groupNoteHistory.getOldText().isEmpty())) {
                groupNoteHistory.setOldText(groupNoteHistory.getOldText()+"." + oldString);
            }else {
                groupNoteHistory.setOldText(oldString);
            }
        }else {
            groupNoteHistory.setOldText(oldString);
        }
    }
}
```

Database screenshots :

[image: Check out newNoteText]

Old NoteText :

[image: Check out oldText]

Thanks a lot... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
String oldString = null;
String newString = null;
```

To

```
String oldString = "";
String newString = "";
```

Comment: That did it, so naive of me.. Thanks a lot my friend.. :-)